# Python multiple if statements in one function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am a new Python programmer. I want the user to select from a dropdown menu one of three items (Blue, Purple, or yellow), and based on their selection, I want a set of volumes to display on another section of the form. I am trying to write multiple "if" statements in one function. As written it will execute the first "if" statement and the "else" but will not execute the two middle "if" statements. What am I doing wrong?

```
    def selected(event):
        if Clicked.get() == "Blue 50-1,000 µl":
            Volume1 = Label(root, text="0.1000")
            Volume2 = Label(root, text="0.5000")
            Volume3 = Label(root, text="1.0000")
            Volume1.place(x=175, y=520)
            Volume2.place(x=525, y=520)
            Volume3.place(x=825, y=520)
        elif Clicked.get() == "Yellow 5-100 µl":
            Volume1 = Label(root, test="0.0100")
            Volume2 = Label(root, text="0.0500")
            Volume3 = Label(root, text="0.1000")
            Volume1.place(x=175, y=520)
            Volume2.place(x=525, y=520)
            Volume3.place(x=825, y=520)
        elif Clicked.get() == "Purple 0.2 – 5 ml":
            Volume1 = Label(root, test="0.5000")
            Volume2 = Label(root, text="2.5000")
            Volume3 = Label(root, text="5.000")
            Volume1.place(x=175, y=520)
            Volume2.place(x=525, y=520)
            Volume3.place(x=825, y=520)
        else:
            Volume1 = Entry(root)
            Volume2 = Entry(root)
            Volume3 = Entry(root)
            Volume1.place(x=175, y=520, width=75)
            Volume2.place(x=525, y=520, width=75)
            Volume3.place(x=825, y=520, width=75)
```

This function is working with the following:

```
    #Pipette Options Selection List
    Pipette_Options = [
        "Select",
        "Blue 50-1,000 µl",
        "Yellow 5-100 µl",
        "Purple 0.2 – 5 ml"
     ]
    #Drop-Down for Pipettes
    Clicked = StringVar()
    Clicked.set(Pipette_Options[0])

    Pipette_Drop = OptionMenu(root, Clicked, *Pipette_Options,    command=selected)
    Pipette_Drop.place(x=280, y=445)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `if` rather than `elif`? Though, in your case only one of those can ever be true so it's unclear why this is a problem.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Why would that be a problem here? The conditions are also mutually exclusive, `Clicked.get()` can't have multiple values.

Comment: What is `Clicked`? Are you sure `Clicked.get()` will return the same value two calls in a row?

Comment: Clicked is the action taken from a dropdown box with the choices of the three "if" statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a typo:

compare these lines:

```
    Volume1 = Label(root, test="0.0100")
    Volume2 = Label(root, text="0.0500")
```

**_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-test"**

flag to close

Answer (score 0):

use dictionary instead:

```
def f1():
    Volume1 = Label(root, text="0.1000")
    Volume2 = Label(root, text="0.5000")
    Volume3 = Label(root, text="1.0000")
    Volume1.place(x=175, y=520)
    Volume2.place(x=525, y=520)
    Volume3.place(x=825, y=520)
    
def f2():
    Volume1 = Label(root, test="0.0100")
    Volume2 = Label(root, text="0.0500")
    Volume3 = Label(root, text="0.1000")
    Volume1.place(x=175, y=520)
    Volume2.place(x=525, y=520)
    Volume3.place(x=825, y=520)
def f3():
    Volume1 = Label(root, test="0.0100")
    Volume2 = Label(root, text="0.0500")
    Volume3 = Label(root, text="0.1000")
    Volume1.place(x=175, y=520)
    Volume2.place(x=525, y=520)
    Volume3.place(x=825, y=520)
    
d = {"Blue 50-1,000 µl": f1, 
     "Yellow 5-100 µl": f2,
     "Purple 0.2 – 5 ml": f3}
if d.has_key(Clicked.get()):
     d[Clicked.get()]()
else: 
    print("another action...")
```

Comment: Why would you use a dictionary instead? This impairs readability a lot imo..

Comment: Smart. But you also should handle the "else" part.

Comment: Dictionary still only works for the first if statement.

Comment: The initialization of `Volume1` et al. can be done once before indexing the `dict`, rather than repeated in each function.

Comment: before need to check if the dictionary key is exists?

Answer (score 0):

Python stops if-elif-else statements once it found a hit. So, when `if Clicked.get() == "Blue 50-1,000 µl"` returns `True`, it won't continue to evaluate the rest of the elif/else statements.
As far as I can determine from your code, this should be deliberate.

Comment: Based on how it is written, if the user clicks yellow in the dropdown, the yellow values defined in the "if" statement should be displayed, correct? That is not happening.

Comment: I have no idea what `Clicked` is, nor what 'Blue 50-1,000 µl" means in this context. The issue doesn't seem to be in your if-elif-else statement but with the return value of 'Clicked.get()'.

Answer (score 0):

if you want 'if' and 'else' to run together as you stated why not merge them together. I think your code need more description. what exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `else` option is not possible (or at least not desirable) in your program. Once you get rid of it, you can get a very flexible solution:

```
def selected(event):
    opt = Clicked.get()
    params = {
        "Blue 50-1,000 µl":
         {"text": ["0.1000", "0.5000", "1.0000"],
          "x"   : [175, 525, 520],
          "y"   : [520, 520, 520]},
         # The other two options go here
    }
    volumes = [Label(root, text=params[opt]["text"][i]) for i in range(3)]
    for i in range(3):
        volumes[i].place(x=params[opt]["x"][i], y=params[opt]["y"][i])
```